# Find the lowest value for a lower norm subject to norm-2 being infinite

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, special-functions, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

This is a follow up post after my previous question "Find a function that has finite values for lower norm but becomes infinite"

The conclusion there was that there does not exist a non-decreasing function $h : [0,1) \rightarrow \Re^+$ that satisfies $\|h\|_1=1$ and $\|h\|_a\leq 1$, where $a$ is some value in $[1,2)$, i.e. for lower orders of norm, but has $\|h\|_2 = \infty$.

This was answered based on the continuity of $a \mapsto \|h\|_a$, which implies that there only exists a function $h$ with $\|h\|_2=\infty$ if it satisfies $\|h\|\leq c_a$ where $c_a$ increases in $a$.

My question now is that for any fixed $a$ if it is possible to identify the **tightest** $c_a$ such that both $\|h\|\leq c_a$ and $\|h\|_2=\infty$ hold for some $h$.

This appears to be very challenging. It is easier to identify some $c_a$ such that both conditions hold, as we may construct a function that satisfies both conditions. But to figure out whether the $c_a$ is the **tightest** seems much harder. And I have no clue at all how to tackle this. Any thought is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed function $h$, the optimal constants are precisely $c_a = \|h\|_a$.

If you wish optimal constants $c_a$ such that for any smaller constants $d_a < c_a$ there does not exist a function $f$ such that $\|f\|_a \le d_a$ for $a \in [1,2)$ and $\|f\|_2 = +\infty$, then such a sequence $c_a$ cannot exist.

Indeed, let $c_a$ be a sequence of constants, and $f$ a function such that $\|f\|_a \le c_a$ for $a \in [1,2)$ and $\|f\|_2 = +\infty$. Consider the function $\lambda f$ for any $\lambda \in \langle 0, 1\rangle$.

For $a \in [1,2)$ we have $\|\lambda f\|_a = \lambda\|f\|_a \le \lambda c_a$ and $\|\lambda f\|_2 = \lambda \|f\|_2 = +\infty$.

So, the smaller constants $\lambda c_a$ would work as well.